# $ \bigcap\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n, k}$ prove the properties of injection.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

For $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$ we describe $A_{n, k}$ as a set of all functions $f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, such that for for every function $f(n) = k$. For each of sets determined below (A and B) decide which descriptions (from 1 to 6) can be applied and prove that.

$$ (A) \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n, k}$$

$$ (B) \bigcap\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n, k}$$

Descriptions:

1. $\emptyset$
2. $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$
3. all functions $f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ that are injective
4. all functions $f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ that are surjective
5. all functions $f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ that are constant
6. none of those

FIrst of all, as I understand, we can interpret the sets as:

$$ (A) \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n, k} = \exists n \forall k$$

$$ (B) \bigcap\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n, k} = \forall k \exists n$$

Descriptions with my thinking and answers:

1. $\emptyset$ $\implies $ I think that it is $A$ because there are no $n$ (arguments of function) that would return all $y$ (possible values of function)
2. $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ $\implies $ none
3. all functions $f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ that are injective $\implies $ none
4. all functions $f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ that are surjective $\implies $ I am sure that it is $B$ because if for all $y$ (possible values of function) exists some $n$ (argument of function) that returns that value, then that is a surjection
5. all functions $f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ that are constant $\implies $ none
6. none of those  $\implies$ X

The problem is that I need to prove that my answers are correct (if they are). I don't know how to do that but it seems pretty repetitive (I suppose it has to be done "both ways") I would be very grateful if  somebody could prove one of them so that I can try to do similarly all the others by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For A suppose there is some $f \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n,k}$. Then, by definition, there is some $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f \in A_{n_0,k}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence by definition of $A_{n_0,k}$,
$$
f(n_0)=k, \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
Which is a contradiction. Hence $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n,k}$ is empty.

For B suppose there is some $f \in \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n,k}$. Then by definition for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there is some $n_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f\in A_{n_k,k}$...(Try to show that f is surjective and then you have $\bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{n,k} \subseteq \{f \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \mid f \ is \ surjective\}$). For the other inclusion suppose $f$ is surjective. Hence by definition for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there is some $n_k$ such that $f(n_k)=k$...